# Authentication in header Rest Api

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, authentication

I am working with `rest api` in **codeigniter** and I want to add `api-authentication`,so for this I am sending 
`access_token` in header section of postman, but I want to know that how can I get it in `.php` file.
I just want the person who try to hit api without `access_token` or wrong `access_token` should not get api results.
In my `controller` I put following code. How can I add authentication on rest api ?

```
if ($access_token!= $_POST['access_token']) {
   echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";

} else {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'any text';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are creating RESTful server in codeigniter, consider using https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver library.

And for API authentication implementation in codeigniter, consider using https://github.com/ParitoshVaidya/CodeIgniter-JWT-Sample.